# How to read text file using get()?

Tags: c++, file, get

I have a text file:

```
a100011
b010100
c001100
```

I want to write it to this map:

```
map<char, vector<bool>> dict;
```

Question: How can I do it using GET()? (this is important)

```
ifstream Dictionary(Dict);
char c;
while (Dictionary.get(c))
{
    //write character and its code to a map
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to use get? Also when you say it's important that you use get does it have to be that version of get? Are the lines in the text file all that same length?

Comment: @DavidOldford the codes are of various length. Sometimes there could be a space or a newline instead of a character, so the simple loop "for (string str; Dictionary >> str;)" doesn't catch that symbols

Comment: Simplify your life.  Read the text line into a `std::string` using `std::getline`.  Then process the string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with line-based data, you should use `std::getline()` to read each line.  You can use a `std::istringstream` to parse each line as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::map<char, std::vector<bool>> dict;

std::ifstream Dictionary("file.txt");
std::string line;
    
while (std::getline(Dictionary, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::vector<bool> vec;
    char key, c;
    iss >> key;
    while (iss >> c) vec.push_back(c == '1');
    dict[key] = std::move(vec);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/anKPkY)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `get()`.

According to your sample input, your records are separated by newlines, i.e. one record per text line.  So, read by line (much more efficient).

```
std::string text_line;
std::map<char, std::string> database;
while (std::getline(Dictionary, text_line))
{
    const char key = text_line[0];
    text_line.erase(0,1);
    database[key] = text_line;
}
```

This is one example.  There more `std::string` methods that you can use to separate the key from the value in the string read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use get for some reason there is a solution below. You can see that it is much more verbose than Remy Lebeau's solution (which I did use as a starting point for mine). Personally I prefer my check of !='0' vice == 1 as if there are any other numbers normally 0 is false and all other numbers are true, but it's more likely an error condition you'd want to catch and bring to a user's attention anyway. I voted for Remy's solution it's shorter easier to understand and easier to maintain. I did add a check for spaces in the input which are skipped, you'd want to add additional logic to handle any other characters you might want to skip or flag errors based on. Depending on how many you might want to test ranges using less than and/or greater than and you may want to use a switch statement.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    istream &inFile = cin;
    map<char,std::vector<bool>> dict;
    while(inFile.eof() == false){
        char key = inFile.get();
        if(key == '\n' || key == 0) continue;
        vector<bool> inefficientBitfield;
        char newChar = 'a';
        while(inFile.eof() == false){
            newChar = inFile.get();
            if(newChar == '\n' || newChar == 0) break;
            if(newChar == ' ') continue;
            inefficientBitfield.push_back(!(newChar == '0'));
        }
        dict[key] = move(inefficientBitfield);
            
    }
    
        for(auto &p : dict)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " =";
        for(auto b : p.second) {
            std::cout << ' ' << std::boolalpha << b;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```